# Error during Intellij idea remote Tomcat Server debug

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I've some problems during configuration of remote Tomcat Server in Intellij
I've got a java web app that need to run in a cluster configuration, so I've got 3 Linux VMS in which I've installed tomcat server.

The problem is that I need to use this 3 tomcat servers together in debug mode in order to test and check issues.
I've tried some things but I was not able to get a solution.

---

OPTION A: configuring Remote JVM Debug:
I've tried to configure a Remote JVM Debug on my intellij configuring Catalina to listen to another port (2001) and launch it with the command: `sh catalina.sh jpda start -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:2001` but it stucks on this message "Connected to the target VM, address: '*IP:2001*', transport: 'socket'"

---

OPTION B: remote Tomcat server:
I've tried configuring a remote Tomcat server (that is the thing I prefer) configuring remote host with SFTP, but in this case Tomcat service start, it works for some minutes and after that it goes in TimeoutException
[[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmDKx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LidfX.png)

I hope anyone can help me, I read a lot of thing on the internet but no-one works.

Comment: Option A: The message "Connected to the target VM" means that debugger was managed to connect to the server. Try to put breakpoints in the code to see if it works. Ensure that the app you need to debug is launched in debug mode. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html

Comment: Option B: Please provide a complete TimeoutException stack trace